# Questions and "1 reputation profiles"

Tags: feature-request, questions, badges, users, privileges

I was wondering is there is some sort of mechanism against the profiles with 1 reputation and 1 badge. Some users are asking a lot of questions and never respond.

Stackoverflow could have something like: when you are "1 - 1 profile" you can only ask one question, at the time. And need to have more privilege before asking more.

Comment: How many 1 reputation users do we have that are actually providing problematic quantities of questions? We have run into many problems with users that ask a lot of questions but don't give back, but has it been a huge problem among 1-rep users?

Comment: StackOverflow is Q&A site - asking questions is the core of the website. People don't even have to register to ask questions, they can ask it 100% anonymously so it's useless to restrict those with profile - they will simply ask without profile.

Comment: I did not knew that, so people with name like userXXXXX are not registred?